# Generate sphinx documentation from Python and C

Tags: python, c, python-sphinx

I have a Python package that includes C code compiled into `.so`.  In my Python code, I have docstrings. In my C code, I also have docstrings. Will `sphinx` be also sensitive to the docstrings given in the C source code, so that I can generate documentation automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming you mean docstrings that are available to the python interpreter as part of a compiled module.  For example:

```
static PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    ...
    {"convolve",
     Pconvolve,
     METH_VARARGS,
     "convolve(xi,yi,x,dx,y): compute convolution of width dx[k] at points x[k],\nreturned in y[k]"
    },
    ...

    {0}
} ;
```

.

The usual `autodoc` magic will pick them up.

If you mean docstrings in C comments beside C functions like in doxygen, then no.  You will have to write your own code to extract them and convert them to rst files.

Comment: For example, I have a Python function defined in C called `foobar()`. In Python interpreter, I can do `>>> help(foobar)`. Its docstrings, written in the C source code, will appear in the Python interpreter. Is that what you mean by "available to the Python interpreter" (and subsequently to Sphinx)?

Comment: Yes.  The example above shows how to set the docstrings in your C methods.  You can retrieve them using the `automodule` directive in sphinx.